# Custom fields that don't have 'required: True' are not appearing in describe call

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, metadata-api, bulk-api

I create a Custom Object named `'SomeTemplate__c'` with the Metadata API, and I have fields:

`'created_at__c'`
`'name__c'`
`'template_id__c'`

which are created with `required: True` set in the parameters. Those fields appear in the describe response's `'fields'` field. These fields:

`'updated_at__c'`
`'is_active__c'`
`'is_weighted__c'`

do not have `required` set in the parameters at all. Though these fields appear in the Object Manager UI for `'SomeTemplate__c'`'s "Fields & Relationships" (so I know the Metadata API call succeeded for them), they do NOT appear in the desrcibe response's `'fields'` field, like the `required` fields do.

Not only do they not show in that describe call, I also can't set those fields when inserting objects via the Bulk API. The insert call errors and tells me

`Field name not found : is_active__c`

So it feels like those fields weren't created (except that I can see them in the Salesforce website's Object Manager).

What is this weird behavior with required fields vs. non-required fields?

QUICK UPDATE:
I can update the visibility using the Salesforce website (Object Manager -> Field Accessibility) by checking the box for "Visible", under both "Field-Level Security" and "Page Layout". After doing that I can now see `'is_active__c'` in the describe call. But using the website is not a valid solution, since I need to do this via the API for many accounts, which I don't have dashboard access to since my API access for them is only via oAuth.

NOTE:
I can't simply make those fields required because `'updated_at__c'` is not always going to exist, and the others are of type `'Checkbox'` which, according to a different insert error message, cannot be `required`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating `CustomObject` and `CustomField` metadata objects via some API call in whatever language or tool, when you go to insert objects of that custom type you made, you won't be able to set any fields that were not `required: true`, because non-required fields are created with visibility as false.

(You can see this in your Salesforce account's Object Manager => your object => Fields and Relationships => your field => Set Field Level Security, and see the unchecked boxes.)

An easy fix is to modify your existing `Profile` metadata object. For me, that meant setting the Profile whose `fullName` was `Admin`, to have these `fieldPermissions`:

```
'fieldPermissions': {
    'editable': True,
    'field': 'SomeCustomObject__c.is_active__c'
}
```

I'm not sure if all API calls are done as `Admin`, but for me that was the relevent Profile to update.

As for HOW to do this update, however you're making your `createMetadata` call for CustomObjects and CustomFields, instead do an `updateMetadata` call, passing in `'fullName': 'Admin'`, or whichever Profile you're updating.

So for me, in Python, I did:

```
sapi.request('updateMetadata', {
    'metadata': sapi._get_api_obj('Profile', {
        'fullName': 'Admin',
        'fieldPermissions': {
            'editable': True,
            'field': 'SomeCustomObject__c.is_active__c'
        }
    })
})
```

to allow me to then insert `SomeCustomObject__c` objects including the field `is_active__c`.

(I'm using [zeep](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/), and `sapi.request`, and `sapi._get_api_obj` are part of a little wrapper I made for Salesforce's SOAP api.)

Answer (score 1):

Your profile doesn't have at least "read" access to the field(s) in question. When you deploy via the Metadata API, the default access is "hidden" for non-required fields, and "editable" for required fields. You would need to either bundle in the appropriate permissions for the fields in the various Profile objects, or modify them after deployment in the UI (e.g. Setup > Create > Objects > Object Name > Field Name > Set Field-Level Security). You'll want to look at the [Profile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm) object for more details.

In your deployment, you'll want to have a "profiles" folder, with files for each profile, such as `Admin.profile`, with the appropriate permission set:

```
<fieldLevelSecurities>
  <editable>true</editable>
  <readable>true</readable>
  <field>Object__c.Field__c</field>
</fieldLevelSecurities>
```

You'll probably want to retrieve a profile with a field to see how it's designed. Try a package.xml that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Object__c.Field__c</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Admin</members>
        <name>Profile</name>
    </types>
    <version>40.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: Super helpful! But still slightly confused about Profiles. In "Set Field-Level Security" page, I see a list which includes `Standard User`, `System Administrator`, and when I use Metadata API to insert a Profile, with `fullName: MyProfile` and `fieldPermissions: {'editable': True, 'field': 'MyObj__c.my_field__c'}`, then `MyProfile` is added to this security page list, for that field, with "Visisble" checked. But how can I set the permission for an _existing_ profile (like System Administrator, or better, yet all of them), in order to be able to insert objects with that field via the API.

Comment: By the way, it appears that one makes API calls as the System Administrator. I checked off the box (for making `'MyObject.is_active__c'` visible) for System Administrator, then I could insert objects that included the field `'is_active__c'`. For contrast, I instead checked the box for Standard User and not System Administrator, and could no longer insert objects that include `'is_active__c'`.

Comment: @tscizzle You'll want to retrieve the list of profiles via listMetadata, then construct the appropriate profile files to deploy permissions for.

Comment: I've listed the Profile metadatas and see their structure. So far my code is all Python, rather than manually creating xml files. I can create a Profile object with a Python line like this: `sapi.request('createMetadata', {'metadata': Profile({'fullName': 'ProfileName', 'fieldPermissions': {'editable': True, 'field': 'MyObject__c.is_active__c'}})})`. Instead of adding extra xml files, I'd like to just modify my call so that it updates an existing Profile instead of making a new one. I'm optimistic that this could be a 1-line change!

Comment: (ANd of course, I don't expect anyone to deal with my Python. I more just want to know the difference, API-wise, between creating a Profile, and updating the pre-existing ones. And then I could modify my call appropriately.)

Comment: @tscizzle The difference is using updateMetadata instead of createMetadata. As long as you specify the fullName, you should be okay.

Comment: Beeautiful. I had tried that, but had something else wrong, and it now works. Much appreciated.